error LNK1169 of std::vector<std::byte> destructor
I know what LNK1169 stands for. So the point is not what this error is, but why it happens, especially since the duplicate defined function is a destructor of an stl template.
The full error is below:
datachannel.lib(datachannel.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::vector<enum std::byte,class std::allocator<enum std::byte> >::~vector<enum std::byte,class std::allocator<enum std::byte> >(void)" (??1?$vector@W4byte@std@@V?$allocator@W4byte@std@@@2@@std@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in media_source.obj [D:\projects\conference-go-client\build\test-uvc.vcxproj]
[build] D:\projects\conference-go-client\build\Debug\test-uvc.exe : fatal error LNK1169: Find one or more symbols with multiple definitions 

In media_source.obj I could find code related to std::vector<std::byte> simplified as follows
// media_source.hpp
    using media_packet_t = std::vector<std::byte>;
    using media_packet_ptr_t = std::shared_ptr<media_packet_t>;
    class MediaReceiver
    {
    public:
        virtual ~MediaReceiver() = default;
        virtual auto request_pkt(close_chan closer) -> asio::awaitable<media_packet_ptr_t> = 0;
        virtual void request_key_frame() = 0;
    };

// media_source.cpp
    struct MediaReceiverImpl
    {
        MediaReceiverImpl(){}

        auto request_pkt(close_chan closer) -> asio::awaitable<media_packet_ptr_t>;
        void request_key_frame();
    };
    struct MediaReceiverWrapper : public MediaReceiver
    {
        using impl_t = unique_smart_node<MediaReceiverImpl>;
        unique_smart_node<MediaReceiverImpl> m_impl;

        MediaReceiverWrapper(impl_t && impl): m_impl(std::move(impl)) {}
        ~MediaReceiverWrapper() = default;
        auto request_pkt(close_chan closer) -> asio::awaitable<media_packet_ptr_t> override
        {
            return m_impl->request_pkt(std::move(closer));
        }
        void request_key_frame() override
        {
            m_impl->request_key_frame();
        }
    };

The std::vector<std::byte> used in libdatachannel should refer to the
namespace rtc {
   using std::byte;
   using binary = std::vector<byte>;
};

In addition, the above error only occurs on windows platform, not on linux with gcc.
Update:
After change my own defined media_packet_t to rtc::binary, the error disappeared. But I'm still trying to figure out why.
  // using media_packet_t = std::vector<std::byte>;
  // using media_packet_ptr_t = std::shared_ptr<media_packet_t>;
  using media_packet_t = rtc::binary;
  using media_packet_ptr_t = std::shared_ptr<media_packet_t>;


OT: You very seldom need a pointer to a container. What problem is media_packet_ptr_t supposed to solve?

Are you using pre-compiled headers?

media_source is using std::vector<std::byte> but libdatachannel is using std::vector<byte>, is it possible that libdatachannel has redefined what byte is and is conflicting with the standard byte?

To avoid copying, media_packet_ptr_t is likely to be shared, so move won't work, and it will end up being passed to libdatachannel, where the type of parameter that needs to be accepted is rtc::binnary = std::vector, but I don't want to introduce the whole rtc/rtc.h in media_sourc just because of this single type, so I'm typedef it again

@3CxEZiVlQ yes, but neither media_source.hpp and rtc.h is included in the pre-compired headers.

@RemyLebeau no, in libdatachannel, it using std::byte;, so std::byte == byte

Using pre-compiled headers is likely a root issue. A [mre] should be posted so I can point to the issue.

@3CxEZiVlQ not relate to pre-compiled headers, After I remove pre-compiled headers, error remains.

I found the key is "rtc/track.hpp" in libdatachannel
class RTC_CPP_EXPORT Track final : private CheshireCat<impl::Track>, public Channel {
public:
    void onFrame(std::function<void(binary data, FrameInfo frame)> callback);
};

If I include this header, the issue disappeared. It seems that RTC_CPP_EXPORT is the key. it is __declspec(dllimport) on windows, but nothing on linux. So the issue only happen on windows.
I'm not sure exactly why yet, but it should have something to do with it

As a windows programmer I expect RTC_CPP_EXPORT to switch between __declspec(dllexport) when your building the shared library to __declspec(dllimport) when you are using the library with some other project. This msdn article explains this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170 see the usage of the MATHLIBRARY_API macro and the MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS preprocessor symbol.
